# Binary I/O to file with 2 dimensional dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, serialization, dynamic, binary

I am having troubles with I/O to file with 2 dimensional dynamic array. It compiles good but it does not work as I want. Example, I save "map" of numbers 1 and after this I change number in source code to example 5 and compile it, now I load my "map" of numbers 1 but when it writes in cycle for at the end it, the output is 5 not 1. Please can somebody help to fix the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
int ** array;

array = new int*[20];
for(int y=0;y<20;y++)
    array[y] = new int[30];

for(int y=0;y < 20;y++)
    for(int x=0;x < 30;x++)
        array[y][x] = 1;

int volba = 1;
std::cin >> volba;

if(volba)
{
    std::ifstream in("map",std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if(!in.is_open())
        std::cout << "in map open error\n";
    in.read((char*)&array, sizeof(array));
    in.close();
    std::cout << "loaded\n";
}
else
{
    std::ofstream out("map",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if(!out.is_open())
        std::cout << "out map open error\n";
    out.write((char*)&array, sizeof(array));
    out.close();
    std::cout << "saved\n";
}

std::cout << "array\n";
for(int y=0;y < 20;y++)
{
    for(int x=0;x < 30;x++)
        std::cout << array[y][x] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

for(int y=0;y<20;y++)
    delete [] array[y];
delete [] array;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is this: Hereby

```
array = new int*[20];
```

you allocate an array of pointers, and this will not become a two dimensional array as you later do:

```
array[y] = new int[30];
```

Note that there is a difference between this

```
// array of pointers to integer arrays
int ** array = new int*[20];
for(int y=0;y<20;y++)
  array[y] = new int[30];
```

and this

```
// two dimensional integer array
int array[20][30];
```

You cannot assume that your array of arrays will lie in contiguous memory.

---

Besides:
Hereby

```
out.write((char*)&array, sizeof(array));
```

you just write out the pointer, not the actual data. Try to print the `sizeof(array)`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int * array = new int[10];
  std::cout << sizeof(array) << std::endl; // probably prints 4 or 8
  return 0;
}
```

---

Conclusion: Unless you need to implement this for educational purposes, [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will far more conveniently serve you memory management for free. Also have a look on [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). It provides functionality for serialization of STL collections.

Comment: @user1295618 - I have put an option in bold. You could alternatively use a static two-dimensional `array[20][30]`.

Comment: @user1295618 - of course not. The good programming way would be to use `std::vector` and probably Boost Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the fact that `sizeof(array)` equals to the size of a *pointer*, not the size of dynamically allocated memory. As an effect, you read/write only 4 (or 8) bytes. Use actual array size (in this case `20*30`) instead of `sizeof(array)`.

Comment: I tried to change sizeof(array) to sizeof(int) * 600 but I have still this problem: "Example, I save "map" of numbers 1 and after this I change number in source code to example 5 and compile it, now I load my "map" of numbers 1 but when it writes in cycle for at the end it, the output is 5 not 1."

Comment: There is another problem in your code, see the answer by @moooeeeep.